# Is the Blitz edge action too strong?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, shadowrun

Blitz (Spend) lets you

> Roll the max dice (5) for a single combat turn

Personally, I have banned this edge action in my games. It just seems *way* too good. It seems to conflict with Seize the Initiative (Spend) in terms of use as well:

> Move to the top of the Initiative Order for the duration of the combat turn

I understand the difference between "I am sure to go first" and "I am going to go many times", but my question is how does this edge action play out in practice?

I banned it due to seeing some scary thoughts of combat mages rolling on par [or even higher] than street samurai, blowing apart teams with Initiative scores of 30+ while the other characters who didn't edge sit on scores in the 10s. It seems like a scary ability that can allow one character to dominate anyone else who didn't edge.

Is it really that good or can it actually be a fun ability to play with? Does it actually work out badly or well in play? Is 1 point of edge worth 30 Initiative score or is 30 Initiative score with blitz even common?

Comment: Whoops words, yeah there was an approved edit to fix those i-words. I just don't allow my players or NPCs to use blitz, but they can use seize the initiative. 
The edge rules says you can not use both at the same time.

Comment: @T.J.L, its 5d6 + your ini+rea, so hitting 30 is a bit more common when you add 6~10 base from stats

Comment: If a combat mage would "blow the opposing team apart" whole teams in a single initiative pass, you should probably use better opponents and not put every single one of them in a area where they could be hit by a single fireball. (and you probably should not use option 4 from run & gun)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edge** is valuable, powerful, and limited. It's also impossible to regain without the GM's discretion. The GM is supposed to give it back when the player does something cool or impressive. As a long-time SR GM, I advise you to only restore Edge when that cool or impressive action *didn't require Edge to begin with*.

**Blitz** is powerful, but Edge is supposed to be. It's actually less useful for Combat Mages than it may seem, because any *combat* mage worth the name should have **Increase Reflexes** (SR5, p. 288) on a **Spell Sustaining Focus** (SR5, p. 320).

A Sammy is likely to have **Reaction Enhancers** and **Wired Reflexes** (SR5, p. 455). In addition to extra Initiative Dice, these systems increase **Reaction** directly, providing a static bonus to the **Initiative Attribute** (SR5, p. 159).

**Blitz** only provides dice, and it doesn't stack with anything (it just pushes it straight to the cap). You ask if a point of **Edge** is "worth" 30 **Initiative Score**, but rolling 30 on 5d6 is unlikely. A roll of 16-19 represents 39% of the possible rolls. The chance of a 30 is significantly less than a full percentage point. (The direct bonuses don't have any effect on the probability of the dice, just the final result.)

Seeing as a character with cybernetic or magically enhanced Initiative is *also* going to have a higher **Initiative Attribute** *before* the dice are rolled, the effect of **Blitz** is somewhat less dramatic than you believe. **Blitz** is most effective on people who probably shouldn't be anywhere near combat anyway, like wage slaves.

Besides, it'll be nice every now and then, but unless the GM is excessively generous with **Edge** refresh, the players should always be thinking: "Is spending Edge on *this* really *that* important, or do I want to keep it to save my bacon *later*?"

Comment: Furthermore you have 1 initiative dice by default, which means *Blitz* doesn't give you +30 initiative, but +24 initiative at most (and an expected value of +14 initiative and the probability of +24 still being < 8‰)